# Moving mouse cursor in panel

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, panel

I'm trying to move my cursor to a position from my panel, when I try this my cursor moves, but not to my panel's position but to that of the main menu, does anyone know what to do to get the position of my panel ?

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Handle);
Cursor.Position = new Point(attach.X, attach.Y);
```

Comment: Please specify the **platform**: is it WinForms, WPF, Xamarin, something else?

Comment: Assuming *WinForms* `Cursor.Position = myPanel.PointToScreen(new Point(attach.X, attach.Y));` if `attach.X, attach.Y` are coordinates on `myPanel`

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

When setting `Cursor`'s coorinates you should provide *screen* coordinates, not *local* ones. Assuming `attach.X, attach.Y` are coordinates on `myPanel`:

```
 Cursor.Position = myPanel.PointToScreen(new Point(attach.X, attach.Y));
```